# Alert Dialog Generico para multiples Activityes en Android Studio

Tags: android, alertdialog

Estoy en desarrollo de una aplicación la cual consta de varias Activitys. Necesito crear un `Alert Dialog` que notifique la acción guardar en cada una de ellas.Mi preguntas es la siguiente ¿De que manera puedo crear un Arlert Dialog generico y llamarlo desde cada `Activity` cuando sea necesario?.esto con el fin de no crear el mismo `Alertialog` en cada Activity. Espero me puedan orientar.De antemano Muchas gracias.

Comment: Las preguntas pidiendo recomendaciones código, frameworks, plugins, etc. se consideran como basadas en opiniones y no se ajustan bien al formato/contenido del sitio. Lee [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para más información. También completa el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender más sobre el sitio y su funcionamiento general (y con ello ganarás tu primera medalla)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo debes crear un clase y pasarle a través de su contructor el contexto:

clase generica:

```
public class Dialog {
Activity activity;

public Dialog(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;

}
public void confirm() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    builder.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FF0000'><b>Este es un ejemplo </font>"))
            .setNegativeButton(Html.fromHtml("Cancelar"), null)
            .setPositiveButton(Html.fromHtml("Aceptar"), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Presionaste aceptar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            .setCancelable(false);
    //.create().show();
    AlertDialog a = builder.create();
    a.show();
    Button btnPositivo = a.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
    btnPositivo.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    Button btnNegativo = a.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
    btnNegativo.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
}
```

}

Al momento de usar el dialog solo debes instanciar la clase y pasar el contexto.
ejemplo de uso del dialog:

```
  Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.confirm();
```

Comment: Ayúdanos a que el OP realice sus preguntas basadas en [ask], esto para que la información sea de ayuda no solo para el que pregunto si no para toda la comunidad, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear varios, según la necesidad que tengas de los mismos, luego los llamas según necesites, por que por ejemplo, no siempre necesitaras un `Alertdialog` con 2 botones, en algunos casos sera con uno, quizás necesites que uno solo tenga un botón "ok" y el otro "cancel". Para los 3 casos tienes estas opciones, que puedes aplicar de acuerdo a la acción que vayas a realizar:

**Con solo un botón de ok (El nombre del botón puedes cambiarlo según tu necesidad)**

```
public static AlertDialog ShowDialogSimpleOKButton(Context context, String title, String msg,
                                                DialogInterface.OnClickListener positiveOnClick){

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(msg)
                .setPositiveButton(context.getString(R.string.dialog_ok), positiveOnClick)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .create();
    }
```

**Con solo un botón de cancel (El nombre del botón puedes cambiarlo según tu necesidad)**

```
    public static AlertDialog ShowDialogSimpleCancelButton(Context context, String title, String msg,
                                                       DialogInterface.OnClickListener positiveOnClick){

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(msg)
                .setPositiveButton(context.getString(R.string.dialog_cancel), positiveOnClick)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .create();
    }
```

**Con botón ok y cancel (Puedes colocar las nombres que desees en vez de ok o cancel)**

```
    public static AlertDialog ShowDialogSimpleOKAndCancelButton(Context context, String title, String msg,
                                                       DialogInterface.OnClickListener positiveOnClick,
                                                                DialogInterface.OnClickListener negativeOnClick){

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(msg)
                .setPositiveButton(context.getString(R.string.dialog_ok), positiveOnClick)
                .setNegativeButton(context.getString(R.string.dialog_cancel), negativeOnClick)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .create();
    }
```

Son ejemplos de `AlertDialog` sencillos, los puedes modificar según te convenga.

Answer (score 0):

En Kotlin puedes crear una clase abierta  que tenga como objeto una función
para crear un MaterialAlertDialogBuilder

> https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/dialog/MaterialAlertDialogBuilder

puedes añadir al dialog listener para ejecutar algo determinado cuando acepta el AlertDialog **//click positive** o solo salte sin ejecutar ninguna acción

```
open class Tools {
    companion object{

        fun dialogCustom(activity: Activity, text: String, btnAccept: () -> Unit) {
            val builder = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(activity)
            builder.setMessage(text)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.btnAccept){dialog ,it ->
                        btnAccept()
                        dialog.dismiss()
                    }
            builder.show()
        }
    }
}
```

Ejemplo de uso:

Cambia un text al darle aceptar

```
Tools.dialogCustom(requireActivity(),getString("Test"),{
            tvView.text = "Dialog Aceptado"
        })
```

No ejecuta ninguna acción al darle aceptar

```
Tools.dialogCustom(requireActivity(),getString("Test"))
```

Puedes añadir un botón de cancelar o negativo con

```
.setNegativeButton()
```

Si quieres añadir una función cuando le de cancelar/negative para cuando llamas al dialog puedes hacerlo de la misma forma que el btnAccept:

```
open class Tools {

    companion object{

        fun dialogCustom(activity: Activity, text: String, btnAccept: () -> Unit,btnCancel: () -> Unit) {
            val builder = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(activity)
            builder.setMessage(text)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.btnAccept){dialog ,it ->
                        btnAccept()
                        dialog.dismiss()
                    }
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancelar"){dialog ,it ->
                    btnCancel()
                    dialog.dismiss()
                }
            builder.show()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Un código sin explicación es como un hechizo de Harry Potter: funciona, nadie sabe por qué ni como se aplica en otras circunstancias. Nadie ha aprendido nada.

Comment: @CandidMoe entiendo discúlpame ,ahora espero que se entienda un poco mas saludos

Comment: Ahí quedo mucho mejor.